# Transformation of explanatory variable

Tags: data-transformation, r-squared

I have tried to transform one of my explanatory variables, which is research and development budget per firm per year, to a logarithmic variable.

The p-value of the variable before and after the transformation was the same, and only the value of r-squared changed from 0.018 to 0.019.

My question is should I stay with the transformed variable, or because the change is so insignificant maybe the transformation is unnecessary?

Answer (score 3):

You should transform an explanatory variable when the transformation makes substantive sense.  In this case, taking log(budget) usually does make sense because it makes doubling the budget the inverse of halving the budget, and this seems sensible.

The fact that it didn't change things much may mean that the range of budget in the data is not very big.

Comment: Hi Peter,I have 66 observation which indeed is a small range-do you think that i should drop the idea of taking log(r&d budget)?

Comment: The number of observations has nothing to do with the range. The range is the spread between the biggest and smallest values. Taking log of budget makes substantive sense.